# Rails mark fields as required without the using validates in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have created a form in rails without using object, its a simple hard coded form which has nothing to do with data base in which i want to mark some fields as mandatory or required. Is there a way to do it in rails manner without using JavaScript.

Comment: Which form generator are you using?  Look for the required: attribute, depending on the generator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you aren't wanting to use server side validation and even client side validation with javascript. I hope you won't mind HTML5 though. Just put a `required` attribute in your field.

```
<form action="some action">
  Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Active Model extensions like validations etc. Refer the below screencast. You can add validations and other features to tableless models.

`In Rails 3 the non-database functionality of Active Record is extracted out into Active Model. This allows you to cleanly add validations and other features to tableless models.`[Active Model](http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model)